# The iot.createKeysAndCertificate is not working properly as suggested by AWS. How to fix it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I have the follow code in NodeJs12 (AWS lambda) that works good with the `iot.createKeysAndCertificate` function:

```
const createCertificates = (params) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    iot.createKeysAndCertificate(params, (err, res) => resolve(res)))

...

module.exports.createThing = async (event, context, callback) => {
...
const { certificateArn, certificateId, certificatePem, keyPair } = await createCertificates({ setAsActive: true })
...
```

Following the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Iot.html#createKeysAndCertificate-property) in AWS they suggest to use the follow approach:

```
var params = {
  setAsActive: true || false
};
iot.createKeysAndCertificate(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

And this is what I did in my code:

```
async function test (params) {
  console.log('Inside createKeysAndCertificate')

  const res = iot.createKeysAndCertificate(params, function (err, data) {
    console.log('inside iot.createKeysAndCertificate')
    if (err) {
      console.log('err, err.stack')
      console.log(err, err.stack)
    }
    else {
      console.log('data')
      console.log(data)
    }
  })

  console.log('res')
  console.log(res)

  return res
}

...
const { certificateArn, certificateId, certificatePem, keyPair } = await test({ setAsActive: true })
...
```

The previous code is not working. In the debug session I can't see the message `console.log('inside iot.createKeysAndCertificate')`. That means that the function `iot.createKeysAndCertificate` is not being trigged.

I can't figure out what is wrong. I am using the same suggestion from AWS.